# Measure bytes written to disk over a period time in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac

I’m looking for a way to get the amount of data written to my disk over a period of time.

Specifically, at the end of the day, I would like to be able to find out how many total bytes have been written to my disk over the course of the day.

I’ve been searching for a solution but haven’t had any luck yet. I thought I came close with [`iostat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/iostat.8.html), but that seems to only monitors current activity. I suppose I’m looking for something that can analyze past activity.

Comment: This is not directly related to your question per see, but have you looked into how to measure traffic across a network? Maybe if you search along those lines you might bump into info regarding to how to do the same on internal/external drives? Just an idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You say [`iostat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/iostat.8.html) only monitors current activity, but it is a very flexible/robust tool with lots of options. For example you can achieve your exact goal by following these simple steps.

First, open up the Mac OS X “Terminal” and run this command you can get a list of connected disks:

```
diskutil list
```

On my system the output is something like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HardDisk                499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS HardDisk_BACKUP         120.4 GB   disk1s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS Storage_1               1.9 TB     disk1s3
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *2.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Storage_2               2.0 TB     disk2s2
```

Now look at the partitions to see the disk you wish to check, but make note of the parent `/dev/disk0`, `/dev/disk1`, `/dev/disk2`, etc… disk/device numbers that are displayed. Let’s assume you want to check the data transferred to `disk0`; so enter the following `iostat` command like so:

```
iostat -Id disk0
```

The output on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 system is this:

```
       disk0 
 KB/t xfrs   MB 
17.12 1277872 21364.96
```

That line of data reflects data transfer statistics from the moment the device was mounted to the moment the `iostat` command was run. The two options set for `iostat` are as follows; the text is taken directly from the man page you can review by typing in `man iostat` from the command line:

- **`-d`**: Display only device statistics.  If this flag is turned on, only device statistics will be displayed, unless `-C` or `-U` or `-T` is also specified to enable the display of CPU, load average or TTY statistics.
- **`-I`**: Display total statstics for a given time period, rather than average statistics for each second during that time period.

And the three magic numbers returned—described as `KB/t`, `xfrs` and `MB` —are broken down as follows:

- **KB/t**: kilobytes per transfer
- **xfrs**: total number of transfers
- **MB**: total number of megabytes transferred

And if you want to monitor in realtime—such as an interval of every 3 seconds—you could run this command with the **`-w`** flag:

```
iostat -Idw 3 disk0
```

The output on my Mac OS X 10.9.5 system is as follows:

```
       disk0 
 KB/t xfrs   MB 
17.13 1279283 21396.20 
 8.49  74  0.61 
 8.49  74  0.61 
 8.49  74  0.61 
29.33 193  5.53 
62.97 219 13.47 
50.51 294 14.50
```

The first number is like the first example; cumulative up to the moment the command was run. The next items are updates every 3 seconds. The first 3 items are the disk basically near rest. The next 3 items with higher numbers fluctuating up and down reflect me opening up the drive in the “Finder” and browsing around a bit for this example.

If you wanted to you could integrate these `iostat` commands in a Bash script and maybe run them in a cron job, but that would be out of the scope of this question and answer thread.

Comment: Thanks very much for the very detailed reply Jake, this was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Activity Monitor.  [Applications/Utilities.]

Disk Tab.

[image]